# Will a monitor connected to a usb-hub show image from Android?

Tags: screen, external-keyboard, external-display, mouse

I'd like to connect a VGA monitor to an Android device. I'm thinking to connect a usb-hub to the device, then plug USB to VGA adapter into the hub. Also a mouse and a keyboard are going to be connected to that hub (i.e. to the Android device). Is it going to work or display should be the only thing to be connected to micro-usb port of the Android device?
I.e. this way:

```
Android device -> the hub -> keyboard,
                          -> mouse,
                          -> usb to vga adapter -> display.
```

I were considering such https://a.co/d/hADyUFi

and such

[https://www.amazon.com/Tripp-Lite-Serial-Adapter-U209-000-R/dp/B00005V52C/ref=mp_s_a_1_29?crid=2I0ZITLONHASM&keywords=usb+vga+adapter&qid=1655099821&sprefix=Usb+vga+adapter%2Caps%2C722&sr=8-29#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00005V52C)

types of adapters.

Comment: I don't think that the Android kernel contains the necessary drivers for a USB-to-VGA connector. But in the end it depends on which converter chip us used by the USB-to-VGA converter and which phone model respectively what extensions have been added by the phone manufacturer. So there is no general answer, but I would surprised if you would find a device with the necessary drivers included. If the phone is rooted you could try to build your own kernel and include the drivers.

Comment: Is it a USB-A to VGA adapter or a USB-C one? Does it say "DisplayLink" on it?

Comment: The StarTech product might be using DisplayLink (that's the most common video-over-USB2.0 protocol), and I have no idea whether Android supports DisplayLink though most likely it won't. But the "Tripp-Lite" product in your second Amazon link is **not a VGA adapter at all** – it's an RS-232 serial (aka "COM port") adapter. Note how it has a 9-pin connector (DE-9) while VGA uses a 15-pin one. (Such adapters do actually work with Android for serial communications... but again, it's not a VGA adapter.)

Comment: @user1686 I thought to use A, why it is matter c or a, it's just shape of the connector isn't it? Ive posted 2 links in the question, I thoght to use the blue one. No display link label on them.

Comment: @YaY: Type-C connectors may have "alternate modes" and quite a few smartphones support direct digital video output over their type-C port (usually DisplayPort; in theory also HDMI), while Type-A connectors are always just USB (and therefore need proprietary video-over-USB standards like DisplayLink that phones don't support).